# Cypress topic Custom commands when run is returning a Syntax error

Tags: cypress

I just started learning Cypress a few days ago through Udemy. I am learning Custom commands and in that the tutor created a custom command
Cypress.Commands.add('getbyId',(selector) =>
return cy.get('#${selector}')

When I call this function  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R75TM.png)from a test, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSyhp.png)
I am getting Syntax error unrecognized expression - #${selector}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBO7J.png)
Can anyone please help me solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Syntax errors. I am not sure how to solve this. Cypress version is 10.2.4

Comment: One obvious thing that stands out - did you intend that to be a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Answer (score 4):

The custom command is designed simply to add a `#` character in front of the id you pass in as a parameter.

This gives a selector string that will search for an element with a particular id attribute, for example `<div id="my-id">` will be found with the selector `cy.get('#my-id')`.

The easiest way to concatenate two strings within the custom command is to use the `+` operator.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getbyId', (selector) => return cy.get('#' + selector)
```

This way you can see the code is correct from the start.

The second way pointed out in the comments is using template strings, which ***inserts*** one string into another. Mostly that would be used for more complicated situations than this one.

To use template strings, you need to surround the ***template*** with ***back-ticks***, and the inserted string is designated by `${}`.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getbyId', (selector) => return cy.get(`#${selector}`)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try this option too. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use the template literals with backtick(`) characters.

So, instead of

```
cy.get('#${selector}')
```

You should use

```
cy.get(`#${selector}`)
```

Comment: Oh wow!! Thank you so much. My test passed. I couldn't figure out that small thing. So so kind of you. Thanks for your time.